# How to make the images in 3 columns appear in the same line?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create a portfolio section on the website that I'm creating, with Bootstrap.

However, when I'm trying to line them up, the third one always jumps to the next line, and I don't know how to solve that.

Please see my code, below:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-content-center">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">
      <figure class="figurefx pushup">
        <img src="assets/img/work-sample/hive.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Hive II">
        <figcaption><a href="">Hive II</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">
      <figure class="figurefx pushup">
        <img src="assets/img/work-sample/jackson.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Jackson House">
        <figcaption><a href="">Jackson House</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">
    <figure class="figurefx pushup">
      <img src="assets/img/work-sample/p5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="P5 Residence">
      <figcaption><a href="">P5 Residence</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, if you can put the code into an online editor with the version of Bootstrap that you use, it will be easier to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your markup
Delete this div and it will work

Please indent your code and you will see these kind of mistakes

Good luck

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-content-center">    
    
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">    
      <figure class="figurefx pushup">
        <img src="assets/img/work-sample/hive.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Hive II" />        
        <figcaption>
          <a href="">Hive II</a>
        </figcaption>    
      </figure>    
    </div>    

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">    
      <figure class="figurefx pushup">        
        <img src="assets/img/work-sample/jackson.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Jackson House">
        <figcaption>
          <a href="">Jackson House</a>
        </figcaption>    
      </figure>    
    </div>    
    <!-- removed closing div -->
    <!-- </div> -->

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex">    
      <figure class="figurefx pushup">        
        <img src="assets/img/work-sample/p5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="P5 Residence">
        <figcaption>
          <a href="">P5 Residence</a>
        </figcaption>    
      </figure>    
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```